# Use different separators in the same paste statement R

Tags: r

I am trying to join three columns of a dataframe in one:

```
Chr    Start    End
1       100      105
2       400      420
```

I would like to obtain the coordinates in a column and I am trying this:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(i[,1], i[,2], i[,3], sep=c(':', '-')))
```

This is working except for the separators, because I am not obtaining the "-" as the second separator, so my output is this:

```
coord
1:100:105
2:400:420
```

While my desired output would be :

```
coord
1:100-105
2:400-420
```

How can I use a second separator in the same paste statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of other alternatives to consider using `dplyr` and `paste0` or `sprintf`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(coord = paste0(Chr, ":", Start, "-", End))

df %>%
  mutate(coord = sprintf("%d:%d-%d", Chr, Start, End))
```

**Output**

```
  Chr Start End     coord
1   1   100 105 1:100-105
2   2   400 420 2:400-420
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use two separator characters in a `paste()` statement. Please read the help page of `?paste`. It says:

> sep = a character string to separate the terms. Not NA_character_.

```
df$coord <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(paste(x[1], x[2] , sep=':'), x[3], sep='-'))
df
#   Chr Start End     coord
# 1   1   100 105 1:100-105
# 2   2   400 420 2:400-420
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(coord = str_c(Chr, ":", Start, "-", End))
```